# Interprocess Communication using Named Pipes in C# + PHP

Tags: c#, php, interprocess

Interprocess Communication using Named Pipes in C# is easy, but im not exactly sure how to do this in php, or if its even possible. so i have these questions:

1. Is named pipes possible in php?
2. Is it possible to have a C# named pipe client, connect to a php named pipe server?
3. how the heck would i code that? :)

an answer to any of the above questions would be **so** helpful.. thanks :)

**edit:** Its a stand alone php program, not a web-based app.

**edit2:** The named pipe server can be in the C# side, or the PHP side, it doesnt matter. I have made C# examples for both.. but i dont know where to start for php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use sockets? Why does it have to be a pipe?

Looks like PHP has lots for sockets:
https://www.php.net/sockets

Stream Functions:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.stream.php

Did you see this?
PHP and named pipes: http://my.opera.com/zomg/blog/2007/08/29/php-and-named-pipes

```
<?php
//Open pipe and write some text to it.
//Mode must be r+ or fopen will get stuck.
$pipe = fopen('testpipe','r+');
fwrite($pipe,'this is some text');
fclose($pipe);
?>
```

posix_mkfifo:
http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/function.posix-mkfifo.php

**EDIT** I am assuming you are on windows (C#) so that may not work....

Comment: I suppose if named pipes doesnt work, then that is a possibility.. lets call that plan B :)

Comment: @Tommy: why do you have to steal my name? haha

Comment: no, im on windows. and, i need the pipe to be multi-directional. so, the php needs to open the pipe, be able to write to the pipe, and also wait for input and read anything else sent from the pipe server.

Comment: And, what about reading after writing ?

Answer (score 4):

If it is already created then you can open a named pipe as a file using PHP's `fopen` function.

In windows the pipe "file" path looks like "\\.\pipe\pipe_name", however there is an [open issue](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29005) in PHP which prevents this from working. The workaround is to use the computer's name instead of the dot in the path:

```
$name = php_uname('n');
$pipe = fopen("\\\\" . $strComputername . "\\pipe\\pipe_name", "r+");
```

Though I vote for sockets like Tommy recommended, they're easy, cross-platform, and inter-machine if need be.

Comment: And what about for writing, and for reading ?