# How to communicate between C++ and PHP on Windows?

Tags: php, c++, windows, exec

I've a project that has a program written in C++ (that always has to run) and a Apache web server with PHP on a Windows PC. Now I want to send parameters retrieved from clients in PHP to the C++ program and get an answer back, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I've looked at exec() and shell_exec() in PHP, but they can only execute programs, I want to call a method in C++ and send the return value back to PHP.

Is the best way to temporary store the results in a file or do you have any better ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a socket or use some other OS-provided interop mechanism. (I'd stick with TCP/IP sockets.)

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought of that!

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to use named pipes.

Here are a tutorial how to: 
http://my.opera.com/zomg/blog/2007/08/29/php-and-named-pipes

another answer:
[Interprocess Communication using Named Pipes in C# + PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623198/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-c-php)

making a named pipe for php
http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/function.posix-mkfifo.php

Comment: Note that it is not possible to make a named pipe from PHP on Windows.  Reading and writing to an existing pipe should work fine, however.