# Named pipe in php on Windows/Mac/Linux?

Tags: php, windows, windows-xp, named-pipes

I'm currently using proc_open() in php to communicate with command line tools.  It automatically creates up to 3 file descriptors for STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR because more than 3 pipes breaks Windows compatibility.  It works great on Windows XP and 10.7 on my Mac.

However, I would like to be able to create my own named pipes for better control.  If I'm unable to do so, then I have to maintain references between the process resource and its stream resources, which is overly complicating my code.  I can't use files because they fill up disk space for long tasks.  I'm also trying to avoid using sockets because they aren't enabled by default in php.

Here are the links I have found so far:

http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/557245-named-pipes-windows

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29005

[Interprocess Communication using Named Pipes in C# + PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623198/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-c-sharp-php)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe#In_Windows

http://www.phpkode.com/source/p/xp-framework/xp-framework-xp-framework-554d8b2/core/src/main/php/rdbms/mysqlx/NamedPipe.class.php

I've tried each of these in php 5.3.13 but none of them work:

```
var_dump(fopen("\\\\.\\pipe\\mypipe", "w+"));
var_dump(fopen("\\\\127.0.0.1\\pipe\\mypipe", "w+"));
var_dump(fopen("\\\\".php_uname('n')."\\pipe\\mypipe", "w+"));
```

I always get an error that looks like this:

```
PHP Warning:  fopen(\\.\pipe\mypipe): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\named-pipe.php on line 15
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\named-pipe.php:0
PHP   2. fopen() C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\named-pipe.php:15

Warning: fopen(\\.\pipe\mypipe): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\named-pipe.php on line 15

Call Stack:
    0.0018     431936   1. {main}() C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\named-pipe.php:0
    0.0018     432072   2. fopen() C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\named-pipe.php:15

bool(false)
```

So my question is, has anyone successfully opened a named pipe on Windows XP?  If not, what versions of Windows support named pipes?  I don't know if the pipe "file" descriptor needs to already exist, for example if it has to be created by mysql or other services.

Bonus points if you can supply cross-platform code, perhaps using posix_mkfifo() or system("mkfifo pipe") like in this answer:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php#22801

Ideally the solution should work with a vanilla install of php, so without sockets, etc, but anything helps thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you realy read http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/557245-named-pipes-windows ?

The solution is not to use dots in pipe's name.

All your samples are with dots in pipe's name.

Answer (score 0):

Is this server code you are writing?  It looks like you're using the client side calls perhaps you need to create the pipe first?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx

Not sure you can write the server in php, needs CreateNamedPipe().