# Communication between C# .NET and PHP/Laravel

Tags: c#, php

In my laravel application, I want to provide the users with the opportunity to download a copy of their stored data in the form of a Word document. I found that certain parts of this can only be accomplished using C#/.NET.

For this, I wrote a C# application alongside a method called `GetWordProfile(User user)` which returns `FileInfo` set to the actual path of the output file (this is always within the `storage` folder of laravel, so laravel has access to it). I only need the path and everything's done and dusted since from this point on, I can manage my laravel application to download this for the user.

However, the question is how do I get there? I must not forget about potential errors which may occur and thus display them (the errors are (inside my C# application) handled by `log4net` in a file as well as on the console; same goes for all output).

I tried to run my application using `shell_exec` respectively `exec`, however, both only returned zero results (`null`) (despite having set `$output` for `exec`) and thus seem not to be suitable. Also, I usually don't want loops (inside PHP/laravel) too much since you're then using a lot of computing power which is unnecessary for this sort of task, also you don't want to let your users wait more than, say, 5 secs, seeing nothing in your browser but the script being executed within a blank page (during the execution there's no content, obviously).

EDIT: I also approached the use of `COM` which ultimately did not work properly out either.

What is an appropriate approach towards this?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with Python + C# a while back using IPC (Inter-process Communication) using named pipes.

EDIT: URL is broken. Here's the question someone asked previously on this topic.
[Interprocess Communication using Named Pipes in C# + PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623198/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-c-sharp-php)

Comment: This looks like a start. Thank you!

Comment: As an alternative couldn't you set up a named pipes WCF service and consume it in PHP?

Comment: You're right that would be better, I can't believe I forgot about WCF. Thanks for the comment!